# Override Genexus Grid pagination events

Tags: javascript, pagination, grid, genexus

I created a Standard genexus Grid in a Web Panel. I want to display a message (eg. "If you leave this view changes will not be saved") when my users click on the grid pagination buttons. How can I ovverride the standard javascript to customize the default behavior? I don't want to manage pagination manually.
Thanks in advance

Environment: GX Version: Ev2U5, Generator: Java Web

Answer (score 0):

If you add your own buttons with FirstPage, PreviousPage, NextPage, LastPage methods, GeneXus does not add the default buttons and lets you manage paging.[Wiki References](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/hsearch?nextpage%20method,1)

Answer (score 0):

If you use the method `Grid.GoToPage(&PageNumber)` the grid's automatic paging is disabled.